# Random C++ execution flow when using breakpoints in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I added breakpoints to every line in visual studio 2017 community edition for the following code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

// base class 
class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle()
    {
        cout << " **** This is a Vehicle **** " << endl;
    }
};

// sub class derived from two base classes 
class Car : public Vehicle {

};

// main function 
int main()
{
    // creating object of sub class will 
    // invoke the constructor of base classes 
    Car obj;
    return 0;
}
```

An action is set here to print a debug text when each line is executed.

I build the program then I ran a new debug instance. I got this

[image]

**Output #1 : first 7 lines**

```
main function
class car
blank line inside car class
// sub class derived
vehicle class closed
blank line after car class
// main
```

Then I rebuild the program and ran a new instance and I got this

[image]

**Output #2: first 7 lines**

```
main function bracket open
// main
car class close
class car
blank line inside car class
blank line after car class
blank line after vehicle class
```

I have optimization turned off.

I'm new to C++ and would like to know why this is happening, Is it compiling differently or is there something wrong with the breakpoint action execution?

EDIT: I have added the first 7 lines of the output in the screenshot. There you can see that the order of execution of the breakpoint action is different for the two runs.

**NOTE:** Please note that the output lines you see are added by me using the breakpoint -> action functionality, this way Visual studio will print out my message when that breakpoint is hit. The execution won't stop it will just print out whatever text I put in as the breakpoint action

Comment: [Don't upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Just copy all the input and output texts and paste here

Comment: If I had showed you the code as text then how would you be able to see the breakpoints? Don't downvote a question for such a small reason.

Comment: @Vizkrig it is sufficive to *say* that there are breakpoints. Also, please describe what it is that "this is happening".

Comment: Okay. I added the code and removed the screenshot

Comment: *I added breakpoints to every line* isn't this enough? And I don't know if the output are created by MSVC or just `cout` by you, but isn't it better just to copy the relevant part instead of printing the output including unnecessary things? The tiny text in images is also harder to read

Comment: No need to have removed the image. I'm also death on images, but only if they are used as the sole source of information. As supplementary information they're cool.

Comment: @phuclv "And I don't know if the output are created by MSVC or just cout by you" the output is my custom text inside the breakpoint -> action functionality, this way I would know when each line is being executed as I said in my quesiton. "but isn't it better just to copy the relevant part instead of printing the output including unnecessary things?" Printing out unnecessary lines is the whole point of this experiment. This way I would know when each line is being run by the compiler. What I want to know is why did the output change the second time.

Comment: those *ConsoleApplication1... Loaded...* lines and *thread...* lines don't add any values here and are just noise

Comment: @Vizkrig Again: what is the problem? "when each line is being run by the compiler." the compiler doesn't run anything. "What I want to know is why did the output change the second time." what is the difference? it's not fair to let potential answerers figure that out by looking at two images if you already know.

Comment: I think the confusion here is how whitespacing is interpreted. Breakpoints on empty lines, or lines which do not contain meaningful code, are not guaranteed to work; and in fact, wouldn't in past versions of VS (at least my copy of 2015, the breakpoints would just move to the next line that contains actual code).

Comment: Is it "Why the <expletive deleted> aren't the breakpoints being hit?"

Comment: @Swordfish The problem is that the output is different for the two runs. I have edited the question and added the first 7 lines of each output log, now the difference is pretty clear. And I'm sorry if my question didn't make sense at first. Thank you for patiently pointing that out

Comment: @user4581301 Not exactly. The breakpoints are being hit differently every time. I have edited the answer, hopefully, its easier to understand.

Comment: @phuclv I thought the loading lines might be useful for someone since they denote which dll files are being loaded. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have breakpoints at many lines that do not actually represent executable code. When the application is executed, these breakpoints are moved to the closest executable statement.

You can see that when you actually break at a breakpoint in Visual Studio. Some of the breakpoints seem to be gone, but several breakpoints just moved to reference the same statement.

For the breakpoints that are moved to reference the same statement, the order of their debug messages is not defined.

---

Editor View:

[image]

Debugger view:

[image]

Comment: So you're saying the order of break statements is random for each run?

Comment: @Vizkrig Yes, you end up with 2 or more breakpoints on one line, there is no defined order for multiple breakpoints on the same line to execute in